# Display Object in Display Group is not displayed properly when created in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my project; when the white circle is hold on, the number of zombies is decreased by one. When the number of zombies reach zero, the wave number is increased by one. and the number of zombies are then equal to the number of waves. While that happens, a rectangle at the side is created after the wave value is increased by one.

However, my problem is that the rectangles are constantly being made in the same place where the second rectangle was created and that rectangles are being creating when the wave hasn't changed.

If you still don't understand, just paste the code in and you will.

Here is my code:

```
local wave = 1
local zombies = wave

local rectGroup = display.newGroup()

local rect = display.newRect(rectGroup,display.contentCenterX+90,display.contentCenterY,50,400)

local function moveup()
zombies=zombies-1
rectGroup.y=rectGroup.y+5
end


local needToup = false

local function handleEnterFrame( event )
    if ( needToup == true ) then
        moveup()
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", handleEnterFrame )

local function handleupButton( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        -- Fire the weapon
        needToup = true
    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" and needToup == true ) then
        -- Stop firing the weapon
        needToup = false
    end
    return true
end

local circleup = display.newCircle(display.contentCenterX,display.contentCenterY,40)
circleup:addEventListener("touch",handleupButton)


local waveText = display.newText(wave, display.contentCenterX, 100, native.systemFontBold, 25)
local waveTitle = display.newText("Wave:", waveText.x, waveText.y-20, native.systemFontBold, 25)
local zombiesText = display.newText(zombies, display.contentCenterX, 175, native.systemFontBold, 25)
local zombiesTitle = display.newText("Zombies:", zombiesText.x, zombiesText.y-20, native.systemFontBold, 20)



function zombiesText.enterFrame( self )
   self.text = tostring(zombies)
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", zombiesText )

function zombiesText.finalize( self )
   Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", self )
end
zombiesText:addEventListener("finalize")

function waveText.enterFrame( self )
   self.text = tostring(wave)
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", waveText )

function waveText.finalize( self )
   Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", self )
end
waveText:addEventListener("finalize")



local function gameLoop()
if zombies==0 then
wave=wave+1
zombies=wave
end
if wave>1 then
print("On wave"..tostring(wave))
display.newRect(rectGroup,display.contentCenterX+90,-rectGroup[rectGroup.numChildren].y+70,50,400)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", gameLoop)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", gameLoop)
end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", gameLoop)
```

Comment: How the rectangle should behave? What do you want achieve?